# Word that describes text transformation into a code with data loss

Tags: terminology

I am working with a piece of software code which transforms a character array into a single integer. For example, if I have the array `[ a, b, c ]`, then it becomes 97 + 98 + 99 = 294, for ASCII 'a' = 97, et cetera.

So this code converts an arbitrary-length sequence of characters into a single number. The transformation has the following properties:

- It accepts arbitrary-length input;
- A transformed input cannot be reversed (well, there may be multiple possible inputs to a transformed output, for example, `[a, b, c]` → 294, but also `[b, b, b]`);
- The output is stored into a fixed-size binary number,

I am looking for a word that fits best here. The terms *digest*, *checksum*, *encrypted value/code/text*, *obfuscated text*, *hash*, *cypher*, *encoding*, *lossy compression* or just *transformation* came into my mind.

The transformation *looks* like it is an application of [*lossy compression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). However, I think the algorithm is not meant to compress in order to save space, but instead to encrypt, obfuscate, or at least make sure that humans cannot read the stored value, or have a hard time doing so.

Which word should I use here?

Example usage: "Finally, the input is compared to the ___, and if they're equal, then the access is granted."

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just use “encoded”?

Comment: I don't know exactly whether I should take the *shape* of the transformation or its *intended use* into consideration when choosing a word.

Comment: Is it different from *sum*? Addition produces a sum.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing sounds a lot like a "hashing function", some examples of which are MD5 and SHA-1, and is the correct wording in the computer science-perspective.
The result of a hashing function (= output) is the hash, which follows standardized characteristics (usually length and possible characters) per hashing function.

A key feature of hashing functions is the one-way transformation, meaning that for a given output you can't go back to the initial input with certainty - you can only find "collisions", as in your example for [a b c] and [b b b] producing the same output.

Based on the terms given in your example, I would like to counter some of them:

- "digest" is (afaik) mostly used for the output of the hashing function
- "checksum" describes one specific use case of hashing functions, which is controlling for errors when transferring large arrays / files of data. However, as this is a use case instead of the act of transofrming your input into the output, I would advise against that
- "encrypted value/code/text" are relying on "encrypted" which is functionally different from hashing, as an encryption can be reversed, providing the initial input without uncertainty. Hashing offers no way to reverse it and it is therefore not possible to get back to the input from a given output.
- "obfuscated text" relies on obfuscation, which is usually done with code. "Obfuscated code" means that the code has been actively and willingly made harder to read for humans (e.g. by introducing random jumps that complicate understanding how the computer executes the code). As the "obfuscation" is transparent to machines, the code will behave functionally similar to the original - which is not true for your example.
- "hash" is the output of a hashing function, hence almost there
- "cypher" (or cipher) is usually used as a word in cryptography, and describes the algorithm used to encrypt and decrypt, which is not what your function is able to do
- "encoding" as a process is always accompanied by "decoding", which will return the input
- "lossy compression" is somewhat coming close, but compression implies that the data has been reduced in size but can still be used for similar applications. Your described function will significantly reduce the size but prevents most applications. After all, putting a poem through your function will not result in a presentable poem.
- "transformation" is ok as it is generic, but provides very little information as to what is actually happening